# Is PostGis suitable for Global data routing?

Tags: pgrouting, osm2pgrouting, osm2po

I'm searching quite some time now...

Is it possible to load the global routing data into PostGis?
What can I expect from a performance point of view?
It's for routing purposes only.

I've downloaded the global data, extracted it, saw the 300Gig size and started wondering...   the .osm is 300Gig, but still has to be converted to pgRouting.

Searching on the internet ends up mostly in examples whereas pgRouting is used for boundaries like cities...  hence my question over here.

Thanks for answering, any type of help is useful!

Johan

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to load the global routing data into PostGis? What can I expect from a performance point of view? It's for routing purposes only.

Yes, it's possible to load global data in the database, but it is probably not possible to run long-distance routing requests if you expect a reasonable response time.
But you can make routing queries that clip a small BBOX area from your global data and use it for short-distance routing queries. For performance reasons you should always load not more data than necessary. When your selected data (within BBOX) is < 500.000 records, performance should be OK. Above it depends on your hardware.

> I've downloaded the global data, extracted it, saw the 300Gig size and started wondering... the .osm is 300Gig, but still has to be converted to pgRouting.

With osm2po you can import the whole OSM planet file. I once did that on a very fast SSD server and it doesn't take more than a few hours. It should be still possible on standard hardware in a reasonable time.

Comment: wooow...  thanks for that quick & clear answer :)
Really really helpful, thanks alot!
Does the size of the db is similar to the .osm file, or is it expanded somehow?

Comment: The osm file contains a lot of data that is useless for routing. So a lot of data won't be imported, but I never counted the size of the database so I can't tell how much it is after running osm2po. The database size though also depends on other things like indices for example. So it's difficult to tell, I think.